# Circle relation table in latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex

I want to draw a picture like this in latex, i use xelatex with chinese, which start with

```
\documentclass[UTF8]{ctexart}
```

Could someone told me how to tackle it? thanks

[image]

Comment: The circles can be done easily using `tikz` and the Chinese can be put in nodes. Have a look at the [tikz manual](https://pgf-tikz.github.io/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf) for more details and [this](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/TikZ_package) overleaf tutorial for how to get started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tikz is a great tool for that. You can also define your own functions (here I used `def` not to have errors in case it was already defined before… it allows easy copy/paste of the code) not to repeat yourself.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

{% Begin scope to ensure \myCircleRadius won't disturb the rest of the document
  \def\myCircleRadius[#1]{\draw (-#1,0) circle [radius=#1];}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1] % Adapt the scale to enlarge the whole picture without enlarging the text
    \myCircleRadius[1]
    \myCircleRadius[2]
    \myCircleRadius[3]
    \node at (-1,0) {文章内容};
    \node at (-3,0) {文章内容};
    \node at  (-5,0) {文章内容};
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok thanks！ I'm trying to leran about it

Comment: You should use `\newcommand` for precisely the opposite reason: you ***don't*** want to overwrite an existing command.

Comment: @egreg It makes sense when I do this drawing only once, but in many case I put my drawings in a separate file and I have multiple drawings that redefine commands with the same name that I want to input. Of course, I could "factor" all these commands (assuming they are identical) into the preambule, but it's much harder to read, maintain, and I can't anymore just "copy paste" pictures between multiples articles. That said, if I add a scope (group) + `def`, I get best of both world no? My picture will compile even if the command is already defined, and I won't disturb the rest of the document.

Comment: @tobiasBora Users on this site have been bitten by something like `\foreach\color in{<color list>}{...}`. Careless naming can bite you even if you use grouping.

Comment: @egreg yeah, that makes sense. At least grouping helps with reusing multiple times the same kind of picture, whether we use `def` or `newcommand`.